# Entity Reference multi value fields, filter on parent

Tags: views, entities

I have two content types: Family and Members. Family content type has an entity reference field of type Member and can have unlimited values(multiple values).
My question is: How to create a view that enables me to filter Members based on Family.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Add a **Contextual Filter** in your view, use the "Member" field (Entity Reference guess) from your content type "Family".
- Then add a relation in Relationship section, using the same field (Member).
- Add a *Title* field and use that relation.
- Pass the NID of your family has an Contextual Filter in your preview... you might get all the members of that family.

Notice: in yout Contextual Filter you have to select how will you pass the Contextual Filter (Family's NID in this case). You can add it via URL, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what you want to achieve, but you can approach it in 3 ways:

1. you can display members like any other field on family page;
2. you can create a block listing members on family page (or any page where you can provide family node id as contextual filter);
3. you can create a drop-down of family node titles and select the select the family and corresponding list of members would appear.

---

1. For the first situation you don't need views, you can do it with field UI:
   Goto Content Types > Family > Manage Display> Set Entity Reference field format to Rendered Entity
2. For the second situation, you will have to create a block view ; his page has detailed instructions: https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004
3. For the third situation you basically need to display the list of family as exposed filters in views; you might find this screen-cast helpful: https://youtu.be/4Pdii7aFIvc?t=16m15s